# Unstyled web page in IE6. Not FOUC

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have a very interesting issue with one of the websites I created. It renders fine in Safari, Chrome, Opera, FF, IE7&8 but IE6 does not seem to recognize my stylesheet. I'm not using @import for loading, so it's not a case a FOUC.

The website is using Wordpress but never had an issue like this before with WP.

I might be missing out on something stupid here, can find the problem though.

Any help, suggestion would be very much appreciated.

The website is: http://www.magashegyiturak.ro

Comment: Is there something specific that's not working in IE 6? Or the entire stylesheet isn't loading at all?

Comment: the entire stylesheet is not loading

Comment: Your right this is odd. Even IE 5.5 works with it but not 6. probably means that Microsoft forgot to include something in IE6.

Comment: Try a direct path to it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: i tried using the absolute path as well. neither that nor the "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" doesn't seem to work. or <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?> for that matter.

Comment: then it has to be something that was missing or different from ie5.5 and ie7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE6 is currently choking on your `<meta name="description">` tag. The tag currently contains many out-of-range characters for UTF-8 (above or at `0xF5`)

Removing/fixing your `<meta>` tag enables IE6 to render your page properly again.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. Your answer is correct, thumbs up. I knew it must be something like this. It is working, now I can tinker the css so it renders correctly in IE6 as well :p. Also thank you Jonathan for all the attention and help with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out parts of the CSS till it works and then you can narrow it down to a few lines. You could try commenting the whole thing and do a simple CSS call to see if you can do something at least.

Comment: i tried that as well. i only left a body background in the css. not working.